# Remove data from graph that contains certain text Spotfire

Tags: graph, spotfire

I hope you can help I have a graph see Pic 1. The problem I am facing is that members of my team have created Professional names with the word 'Dummy' in it to test some scenarios

But for the purpose of actual reporting I would like to remove any Professional Name that contains the word 'Dummy' in it.

Is there a way to easily remove the 'Dummy' data from my Bar chart?

Pic 1

[image]

Comment: Hey mate! Hope the whiskey is keeping you warm over there!

Comment: Scsimon my old buddy:-)  I am good over here mate, I hope you are likewise, and Yep getting chilly over here now. Just got through hurricane Ophelia so had a few cans and waited that out :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Philip Connell- You can use the below expression in 'limit data by expression' in properties section of your visualization. This ignores rows containing 'DUMMY' word in NAME Column.

```
not([Name] ~= "DUMMY")
```

**Here is the test output:**

[image]

Comment: Boo YAAH worked like a charm :-)  Thank you ksp585! Thanks again guys for all your help it is really appreciated.Much respect from Dublin :-) I will have another question this morning so please feel free to assist if you see it.